# Script change the pictures. In the finished code

Tags: javascript, jquery, gallery, preloader

**Hello!**
How is it possible to make a very simple animations. **In this code?**
For example, every 5 seconds the picture changed.

Now I have made only one. Necessarily need a preloader.

**And here is the original article.**
http://www.htmldrive.net/items/show/1080/jQuery-useful-preload-image-effect

I removed all unnecessary. I left only the preloader and loading pictures "script.js".
Also on the site, I have only "javascript & jquery".
I removed:  https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js

**I would be grateful for your help.**
Thanks.

```
    #img_url{
    border: 0 none;
    height: 44px;
    width: 614px;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-right: 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#load_img{
    border: 0 none;
    color: #363636;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 33px;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #C5C4C4;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-color: #1F8BCC;
    background-image: none;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 0;
}
#image_content{
    width: 614px;
    height: 944px;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    position: absolute;
    left: -7px;
    top: 66px;
}
#img_holder{
    height:944px;
    width:614px;
    margin:0 auto;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
}
#img_holder img{
    max-width: 614px;
    max-height: 944px;
}
.loadit{background:url("/images/ajaxload.gif") no-repeat scroll center center transparent;}
.credit{font-size:12px;}
```

NEXT BODI

```
  <div id="image_content">
<div id="img_holder" class="loadit"></div>
<div id="img_url" class=""></div>
</div>
```

AND JAVA

```
$(function(){
    LoadImage();
    $("#load_img").click(function(){
        $("#current_img").remove();
        $('#img_holder').addClass('loadit');
        LoadImage();
    });
    function LoadImage(){
        var img_url = $("#img_url").val();
        if(img_url == ''){
            img_url = "images/01.png";
        }
        var img = new Image();
        $(img).load(function(){
            $(this).hide();
            $('#img_holder').removeClass('loadit').append(img);
            $(img).fadeIn();

        }).attr('src',img_url).attr('id','current_img');
    }
});
```

**There is such code. How do I make constantly changing images?**
Preload & next play images:

> `"images/01.png", "images/02.png";`

I think we are talking about different things... Thank you again.

Comment: you _could_ use a css sprite or an svg image with embedded image(s) and simply change the offset

Answer (score 0):

To make function calls in a specific interval check: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Build a method, that loads a img and show it on image done loading.

```
threadID = setInterval(LoadImage, 3000);  //Calls your method every 3 seconds.
```

With clearInterval you can stop this.

```
clearInterval(threadID);
```

e.g.

```
$(document).ready( function () {
   var threadID = setInterval(loadAndDisplayImage, 5000);

   $('button#stop').click(function() {
      clearInterval(threadID);
   });
});

function loadAndDisplayImage() {
   //Code to load and display image;
}
```

Hope I this was helpful.

//EDIT:

if you store your images like this:

image-1
image-2
image-3

you can do it like this:

```
var imageCounter = 0; //imagecounter in global scope
var imageBaseUrl = "http://yourfilehost/image-";
function loadAndDisplayImage() {
    var image = new Image();
    image.onload = displayOnLoad; //function that displays your images;
    image.src = imageBaseUrl + imageCounter ++ ;

    //maybe set up limit
    if(imageCounter >= 5){
        imageCounter = 0;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I do not use the call button.
This fragment in the code I do not use.

I do not understand how to link two URL address and display images on a timer. Example: img_url = "preload_image/images/me-banner.png";  etc.

Comment: you can store your image urls in a array and iterate in the interval method. or as technosaurus mentioned use a css sprite and change position in every interval-call

Comment: I am explained NEW the theme of this issue. If it is not difficult to show me an example of my code. I'm no expert. Thanks.